# Android cursor jumping on deleting text kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-cursor

The issue I am running into is that I have a numeric Edit Text field where the cursor drives me crazy:

Let's say you want to type 11115 but mistype 11116.
The "normal" behavior should be to hit backspace and then type 5.

What is happening though is that after the backspace, the cursor jumps to the front of the 1, and has to be re-positioned to the end of the remaining  "1111" string.

More precisely: Regardless where in the string I delete a number, the cursor always jumps to the front after delete.

I can envision all kinds of workarounds with storing and restoring the cursor position... but
there has to be a better way.

Comment: Do you mean this happens when the user uses backspace on the keyboard, or are you deleting text programmatically? I haven’t seen an EditText behave this way as a user. I don’t know why it would unless you’ve done something to customize its behavior using a TextWatcher or by subclassing it.

Comment: it's user, both in the simulator and phone. No subclassing.

Comment: it happens both in the emulator and in the real app. no subclassing.
BTW Mr. local_nobody, I know that there are rules in forums, but editing out a "thanks" seems to be obsessive...

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out... I was refreshing that field (which is a bug) after the delete... That reset the cursor.

Thanks for your answers!